# Proving the decomposition $N = a^a b^b$ is unique or not

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $a,b,c,d$ be natural numbers. If $a \ge b > 0$, $c \ge d > 0$, $a^a b^b = c^c d^d$, then $a = c$ and $b = d$.

For example, can we find another decomposition of $N$ when $N = 8^8 4^4$ ?
Perhaps this decomposition is unique, I think. But it's difficult to prove.

Comment: @bharb there is a size condition in OP.

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently, the decomposition of $8^84^4$ is unique - one may show that by a pretty short exhaustive search. The general question, however, is **much** harder to crack...

Take a look at this.
$$\begin{align}a&=4\,478\,976&=2^{11}\cdot3^7\\
b&=1 \\
c&=2\,985\,984&=2^{12}\cdot3^6\\
d&=1\,679\,616&=2^8\cdot3^8
\end{align}$$

In short, $a=24g,\;c=16g,\;d=9g$, where $g=GCD(a,c,d)=2^8\cdot3^6$.

Now $a^ab^b=\left(2^{11}\cdot3^7\right)^{24g}=2^{11\cdot24g}\cdot3^{7\cdot24g}=2^{264g}\cdot3^{168g}$.

On the other hand, $c^cd^d=\left(2^{12}\cdot3^6\right)^{16g}\cdot\left(2^8\cdot3^8\right)^{9g}=\left(2^{192g}\cdot3^{96g}\right)\left(2^{72g}\cdot3^{72g}\right)=2^{264g}\cdot3^{168g}$.

Which pretty much answers the titular question with a solid "no".

I don't know whether this is the "smallest" example in any meaningful sense.

On a side note, the similar-looking but *completely* unrelated equation $a!\cdot b!=c!\cdot d!$ has solutions galore.